# How to make a plot of function over 24 orders of magnitude?

Tags: plotting

Assume these parameter definitions first:

```
P0 = 325000000000000000000000000000000/1289899878039;
th = 22 10^-7;
alpha = 15*^6;
p0value = 0.0000697013247924021100000;
Lh = 5 10^-9;
d = 80 10^-9;
A = -2.8490639736294850547486980507937310695688037435690471`40.25650391588118*^\
14;
B = 1.1760120752241583305643404927085980980404601631188207268`37.\
974790074939705*^26;
```

Define two functions

```
tmp[x_] := A E^(x/Lh) + B E^(-x/Lh) + p0value ;
tmp2[x_] := -(alpha P0 th)/(1 - alpha^2 Lh^2) E^(-alpha x);
```

Subtracting them at x=d yields the small number p0value

```
tmp[d] - tmp2[d]
```

> 0.000069701324792402

I  want the plot of `tmp[x] - tmp2[x]` to have a value of p0value (0.0000697013247924021100000) at `x = d` and not to stop at $10^{20}$.

```
LogPlot[{tmp[x] - tmp2[x]}, {x, 0, d}, PlotRange -> {{0, d}, {10^-5, 10^25}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried `MeshFunctions` but without success. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ListLogPlot[{#, tmp[#] - tmp2[#]} & /@ 
   Table[Exp[x], {x, Log[d] - 2, Log[d], 1/128}] , 
   PlotRange -> {{0, d}, {10^-5, 10^25}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd! I just changed the list to exact range (0,d) in order to have all points close to 0 as well : Table[x, {x, 0, d, d/128}].

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you need?

```
LogPlot[{tmp[x] - tmp2[x]}, {x, 0, d}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Simply removing the argument to `PlotRange` (or in this case explicitly setting it to `Automatic` might solve the problem?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the asker wants the point $(d, 0.0000697)$ to be visible on the plot, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: Exactly, I want the point (d,0.0000697) to be on the plot.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a plot of $\log(x)$ vs $\log\left(\text{tmp}(d-x)-\text{tmp2}(d-x)\right)$ if it's the "tail" part what you concern:

```
plotdata = Table[{10^k, tmp[d - 10^k] - tmp2[d - 10^k]}, {k, -40, Log[10, d], 1/10}];
ListLogLogPlot[plotdata, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {10^-5, 10^25}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]